# The Galois closure

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $\Bbb K$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q$ having degree 4, why is the Galois group corresponding to the Galois closure of $\Bbb K$ a subgroup of $S_4$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), one can write $\Bbb K = \Bbb Q(\alpha)$ for some algebraic number $\alpha$ of degree $4$. The Galois group of the Galois closure of $\Bbb K$ acts on the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$; this action identifies the Galois group with a subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you explain a little further about why the second sentence is true?

Comment: Here's a concrete example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Second_example . In general, this is a fundamental property of Galois groups that you might profit from studying further.

Comment: If $\Bbb K$ was Galois, I would understand if the Galois group corresponding to $\Bbb K$ acts on the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.  Why is the Galois closure restricted to act on the roots of the irreducible polynomial that "generates" $\Bbb K$?  If the Galois closure is a bigger field, it would seem that its Galois group is acting on a larger set of objects that might include more than just the roots of $m_\alpha$.

Comment: As it turns out, the Galois closure of $\Bbb K$ is generated by the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks a lot for your help and patience :)